# Unable to add attachment(s) to Mail API in server from localhost

Tags: php, server, localhost, phpmailer, attachment

The below code resides in our server. I want to attach file(s) from my local machine without uploading that to server. How can I do this?

```php
$local_file_name = array('Wall.jpg'); //$_FILES['attachment']['name'];
$local_file_path = array('C:\Users\abc\Downloads\Attachment\Wall.jpg'); //$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$size = sizeof($local_file_name);
for ($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++) {
    $mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($local_file_path[$j]), $local_file_name[$j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code to add the attachment to phpMailer

```
$mail->addAttachment('<folder>/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');
```

Comment: The code is on the server and the file is the local machine. How can the server access the file? This snippet and other work perfectly on the localhost but there is the added complexity of the server and the local files.

Comment: @helios, You can't attach a file, if you cannot open it(which is the case if it is on an inaccessible other machine). Otherwise this answer is a spot on correct answer to your question.


Maybe clarify  you question? E.g. howto upload a file to the server - which after uploading can be attached , or whatever you need(just guessing ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do this. Either upload the file (easy), allow your server to connect to your local machine and access files on it (much harder), host files somewhere else and provide remote access to them.

Comment: Thanks, We'll look into it.